# mysql error happened:Data truncated for column 'endangered' at row 1

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE birds_new
MODIFY COLUMN endangered ENUM(
        'Extinct',
        'Extinct in Wild',
        'Threatened - Critically Endangered',
        'Threatened - Endangered',
        'Threatened - Vulnerable',
        'Lower Risk - Conservation Dependent',
        'Lower Risk - Near Threatened',
        'Lower Risk - Least Concern')
AFTER famliy_id
```

> ERROR:Data truncated for column 'endangered' at row 1 befor this
>   change, endangered use BIT(1)

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem while learning the MySQL with a book written by Russel J.T. Dyer, you just need to update the endangered column to set all the record to 1

```
UPDATE birds_new SET endangered = 1;
```

then you can alter the column endangered,

```
ALTER TABLE birds_new
MODIFY COLUMN endangered ENUM (
   'Extinct'
  ,'Extinct in Wild'
  ,'Threatened - Critically Endangered'
  ,'Threatened - Endangered'
  ,'Threatened - Vulnerable'
  ,'Lower Risk - Conservation Dependent'
  ,'Lower Risk - Near Threatened'
  ,'Lower Risk - Least Concern'
  ) AFTER family_id;
```

Comment: `UPDATE birds_new SET endangered= NULL WHERE TRUE; ` `WHERE` keyword is required

Comment: You can't use this in production if you are updating all the records to some undesirable value